# horizontal scrolling issue on mobile

Tags: html, css, media-queries

On mobile (or scroll the browser to 320px) I'm getting a horizontal scroll, this appears to be assioated with the navigation on mobile as it disappears when the nav is collapsed. Does anybody have any idea what this issue may be?

The live link to my portfolio where the issue is located [here](http://www.sarahp.me/)

Comment: I reduced my browser window all the way till 308px whilst on your website but no horizontal scroll appeared.

Comment: No problem on 320px. I do have a problem between 960px - 1040px with the horizontal scrollbar

Comment: animated fadeInDown is not closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, it's related to your navigation.

You have CSS that specifies a width of 100% (which you then offset, causing the overflow).

If you update your media query and specifically this line:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
    .nav-collapse, .nav-collapse ul {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

From `100%` to say `90%` (just a magic number, which worked for me - you'll probably want to add a new rule that targets mobile devices) and then test, you'll see it removes the `overflow` on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

Use 1.000em value instead of 320pxl